# Entity Framework - Getting all duplicate Persons

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Entity Framework 6

I have a **Person Entity**

```
ID
FirstName
LastName
```

I need to produce a report that has a list of all the people that have the same **firstname** and **lastname**. Grouping gets me the name, but not all the ids.

So I'd need all the full person entities that are duplicates:

```
 117 John Smith
 247 John Smith
```

Is a query to get the duplicates possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like this (assuming `pers` is the list of persons fetched from DB using EF):

```
var x = pers.GroupBy(p => p.FirstName + p.LastName).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.ToList());
```

you will obtain an `IEnumerable<List<Person>>`, where each List has all the properties of each Person (I'm assuming a Person class with properties accordingly).

So for example, you can now do:

```
foreach(var y in x)
{
    foreach(var z in y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} {2}", z.ID, z.FirstName, z.LastName));
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` will do it. The trick is simply how you select from the group.

```
var dupes = people.GroupBy(e => new { e.FirstName, e.LastName })
    .Where(e => e.Count() > 1)
    .Select(e => new
    {
        e.Key.FirstName,
        e.Key.LastName,
        Entities = e.ToList()
    });
```